# How to get selected listbox item to update another listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm very new to wpf and mvvm and I hope this makes sense...

I have a ListBox of CheckBox items.  When I check or uncheck an item, I want to know how to fire an event or whatever that will give me the ability to add the selected items text to different ListBox.

Here's what I've done thus far:

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Target}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsControlEnabled}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding TitleName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Main ViewModel Class:**

```
private ObservableCollection<CheckServerItem> _target = new ObservableCollection<CheckServerItem>();
```

**Small Class to handle checkbox events:**

```
public class CheckServerItem : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isChecked { get; set; }
    private string _Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
    public string TitleName
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TitleName");
        }
    }
}
```

The checks are handled correctly by the small class, but I can't figure out how to have that class either call a method in the Main ViewModel Class that manages the other ListBox or what I should.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One road to go down would be to add events in the viewmodel to listen to the checkboxes

Comment: the other ListBox also uses the same MainViewModel ?

Comment: @SamTheDev, the other listbox is in the MainViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Filippo Vigani, you can also do the following if you only check/uncheck the checkbox by mouse,

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding TitleName}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This option looks most interesting, but I'm not sure to what property I'm binding to in the MainViewModel.  Can you help with that @shahjahan?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend binding the other ListBox's ItemsSource to the same ObservableCollection but then using a Converter to get you just the selected items.  Then you don't have to mess around with attaching and detaching event handlers at all.  The Converter would be:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(object))]
public class IsCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<CheckServerItem> result = new ObservableCollection<CheckServerItem>();
        foreach(CheckServerItem item in (value as ObservableCollection<CheckServerItem>))
        {
            if (item.IsChecked)
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

You would need to put the converter in the Resources section of your App or Window so that you can use it in your ListBox:

```
<this:IsCheckedConverter x:Key="MyIsCheckedConverter" />
```

And then your binding for the other ListBox's ItemsSource would look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Target, Converter={StaticResource MyIsCheckedConverter}}>
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't go about it like this simply because this type of filtering is a prime candidate for something you would want to unit test, or at the very least be able to create temporary code in your VM and be able to step though in the debugger without having the view get in the way. Personally I'd add a second collection to the main view model and do the filtering in there in response to the IsChecked properties changing.

Comment: I'd only add a second collection to the VM if this other listbox serves some sort of functional requirement (i.e. further selection is made and something is done with the secondary selection).  I'm imagining that this secondary listbox is only serving a purpose in the view, which is simply clarifying to the user which items are selected.  I've been down this road before, and it doesn't seem worth it to me to go through the effort of trying to synchronize lists and register/unregister event handlers (and introduce possible memory leaks) to satisfy a non-functional need

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an ICommand and bind it to the Checked RoutedEvent of the CheckBox using AttachedCommandBehaviour (you can get it on nuget):

```
Install-Package AttachedCommandBehavior
```

the xaml would look something like this:

```
...
xmlns:acb="clr-namespace:AttachedCommandBehavior;assembly=AttachedCommandBehavior"
...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Target}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsControlEnabled}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding TitleName}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                <acb:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
                    <acb:BehaviorBinding Event="Checked"
                                         Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    <acb:BehaviorBinding Event="Unchecked"
                                         Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </acb:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and then in your ViewModel you would have a command that handles the check/uncheck event. You can use Prism for a class that implements ICommand which is called DelegateCommand, you can get it from nuget:

```
Install-Package Prism.Core
```

The command in your viewmodel could be something like:

```
private DelegateCommand<CheckServerItem> selectionChangedCommand;

    public DelegateCommand<CheckServerItem> SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectionChangedCommand ?? (this.selectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<CheckServerItem>((x) =>
            {
                if (x.IsChecked)
                {
                    MyOtherList.Add(x);
                } else
                {
                    MyOtherList.Remove(x);
                }
            }));
        }
    }
```